# On importing a maven project, does not displays the Maven dependencies in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

On importing a maven project into Eclipse, does not display the Maven dependencies in Eclipse. The command line `mvn clean install` is a success with all the test cases passed. But I am not able to see the dependencies. Also, I have tried maven clean, maven compile. I am also not able to see errors specified by eclipse if I make any syntax errors. Please let me know what needs to be done.

Comment: Do you have M2E Plugin (Maven Integration for Eclipse) installed and are you importing the project as Maven Project?

Comment: Yes Karol. I have installed M2E Pugin and have imported my project as a Maven Project

Comment: If you check your project's `.project` file is there a line `<nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>`?

Comment: How exactly are you importing the project?

Comment: .project file has the  `<nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>` in it

Comment: Which Eclipse version? Which M2E version? Does the _Maven Dependencies_ folder appear if you create a new simple Maven project inside Eclipse and add any dependency to its POM?